# Bayesian hypothesis testing using posterior samples of estimated parameter

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm modeling recruitment curves using a Hierarchical Bayesian model. There is a key parameter in my recruitment curve, let's call it $P$. I have two groups (A and B) of participants of respective size $N_A$ and $N_B$.

After I have finished fitting recruitment curves, I get estimates for the parameter $P$: $P_A$ of size $(1000, N_A)$ (for group A) and $P_B$ of size $(1000, N_B)$ (for group B), where $1000$ is the no. of posterior samples (post-warmup) that I am collecting.

Now, I want to test the hypothesis that the mean of parameter $P$ for group A is less than that of B.

To test this, I could take the MAP estimates and do a frequentist test. But the problem with this is that MAP estimates are not very reliable in participants where these parameters are not clearly observed. Also, I lose valuable information provided by the posterior samples.

Another way is that, I have setup another Bayesian model where I'm modeling the mean of these parameters.

$\mu_A$, $\mu_B$ $\sim$ Normal$(50, 100)$

[My prior knowledge says the mean lies here. But I'm putting the same prior on both $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$, essentially saying that there is no difference in them (Null Model)]

$\sigma$ $\sim$ HalfCauchy$(1)$

$P_A$ ~ Normal$(\mu_A, \sigma)$

$P_B$ ~ Normal$(\mu_B, \sigma)$

and once I fit them, I'm going to reject the Null Hypothesis if the posterior samples of $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$ follow $\Pr(\mu_A < \mu_B) > .95$.

Is this a valid technique? If so, could you please tell me if it's been used in literature and where I can read about it more?

Other question I have which is possibly out of scope --- how to estimate false positives of such testing procedures (basically, how do I trust such procedures). Also, how sensitive is such a procedure to the number of posterior samples?

Comment: Sorry, I've not seen this proposed in the literature before, but maybe someone else has ... If you have your posterior draws for $P$, and you are simply interested in the differences between the two groups, one could just compare the sample means for each group in each posterior draw ... Your question seems to mixing notions of frequentist testing procedures with Bayesian testing procedures ...